# Let G be a Hamiltonian Graph that is not a cycle. Prove that G has at least 2 vertices of degree $\geq$ 3

Tags: graph-theory

Alright so I know we are given two pieces of information to work with, that $G$ is a hamiltonian graph and that it is not a cycle. $G$ being a hamiltonian graph means that we have a path going through it where we don't ever visit the same vertex twice, but I don't see how this is possible if the graph is not a cycle. I guess I have two questions what information can I deduce from knowing these two things and how can a graph have a hamiltonian cycle, but not **be** a cycle, that doesn't make sense.

Note: I know there is another thread but none of the answers were able to help me

Comment: It doesn't need to use every edge, only every vertex. Take a cycle and connect two distant vertices, for example. The resulting graph is Hamiltonian because you can still traverse the graph around the original cycle, disregarding the additional edge. (And this example of a cycle plus an edge might give you an idea of how to approach the statement you need to prove.)

Comment: @Théophile Would this graph not still be a cycle though since I can create a cycle from this graph? How do I find a graph that is not a cycle but also has a hamiltonian cycle? In your example lets say I have a 4 node cycle, then if we form a connection diagonally we have a hamiltonian path in the manner you described but not sure how it isnt still a cycle

Comment: If the graph *is* a cycle, that means that it is the cycle and nothing more. The graph we've constructed (cycle + diagonal) *contains* a cycle as a subgraph (in fact, it contains three: the outer one, and two smaller ones that each use the diagonal), but we wouldn't call it a cycle, just as we wouldn't say that a cube is a square.